# Kdenlive - cut on point

Tags: kdenlive, tracks, keyboard-shortcut

In Kdenlive, is it possible to cut track on current frame? In Blender I would use "k".

I am able to use the cut tool and click on the current frame position, but it usually involves some offset.

I would like a precise solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out.

The shortcut is "Shift+R".

It's located in top options > timeline > current clip > cut clip.